# Powershell $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() changes DATETIME to NVARCHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, date, datetime

Caveat: I am new to PowerShell...

I am trying to automate a load process for 48 tables.  The table names are all of the format "Vocabulary_MMddyyyy", as in "Vocabulary_12052016".  I have no trouble iterating through the table names and parsing out the MMddyyyy part (the release version for the vocabulary). Powershell does not recognize the '12052016' as a proper datetime format.  So, I do some parsing to build a proper date string that I convert to DateTime with the Get-Date cmdlet:

```
    $version = ($table.Table_name -replace 'Vocabulary_', '').Trim();

    $mm = $version.Substring(0,2);
    $dd = $version.Substring(2,2);
    $yyyy = $version.Substring(4,4);
    $date = $mm + "/" + $dd +"/" + $yyyy

    $startDate = Get-Date -Date $date -Format "d"
    $endDate = ($startDate).AddDays(-1)

     write-host 'Version:   ' $version
     write-host 'StartDate: ' $startDate
     write-host 'EndDate:   ' $endDate
```

This properly sets $startDate and $endDates (though despite the "d" format, I still get HH:MM:SS AM part):

```
Version:    12052016
StartDate:  12/5/2016 12:00:00 AM 
EndDate:    12/4/2016 12:00:00 AM
```

This is the SQL signature of the stored procedure I want to call:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [vocab].[prInsertLoadProcessID] (
    @CodeQualifierID            INT,
    @SourceVersion              VARCHAR(100),
    @SourceDate                 DATE,
    @LoadTypeID                 INT,
    @isTestLoad                 BIT,
    @ValidationDate             DATE,
    @LoadDescription            VARCHAR(500),
    @GlobalEffectiveDateStart   DATE,
    @GlobalEffectiveDateEnd     DATE
)
```

Now, I go to build up a SQL command to execute the stored procedure ($conn2 is properly defined and open; it executes simple select statements yielding correct results):

```
    $cmd.Connection = $conn2;
    $cmd.CommandText = "vocab.prInsertLoadProcessID ";
    $cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure;

    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
    $cmd.Connection = $conn2;
    $cmd.CommandText = "vocab.prInsertLoadProcessID ";
    $cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure;

    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodeQualifierID", 6);
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SourceVersion", $version);
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SourceDate", $startDate);
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoadTypeID", 1);
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isTestLoad", 0);
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ValidationDate", 'NULL');
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoadDescription", $LoadDescription);
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GlobalEffectiveDateStart", $startDate);
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GlobalEffectiveDateEnd", $endDate);
```

Each of the dates (@SourceDate, @GlobalEffectiveDateStart, @GlobalEffectiveDateEnd) show as DateTime when I look at the output from adding the parameters (here is one example):

```
CompareInfo                     : None
XmlSchemaCollectionDatabase     : 
XmlSchemaCollectionOwningSchema : 
XmlSchemaCollectionName         : 
ForceColumnEncryption           : False
**DbType                          : DateTime**
LocaleId                        : 0
**ParameterName                   : @GlobalEffectiveDateEnd**
Precision                       : 0
Scale                           : 0
**SqlDbType                       : DateTime**
SqlValue                        : 12/6/2015 12:00:00 AM
UdtTypeName                     : 
TypeName                        : 
Value                           : 12/6/2015 12:00:00 AM
Direction                       : Input
IsNullable                      : False
Offset                          : 0
Size                            : 0
SourceColumn                    : 
SourceColumnNullMapping         : False
SourceVersion                   : Current
```

When I run $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() I get:
Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Error converting data 
type nvarchar to date." this is a Category: MethodInvocationException and a FullyQualifiedErroID: SQLException.

So, after reading for hours and trying everything I can think of I am stuck. My variables appear to be typed as DATETIME, but ExecuteNonQuery() seems to read treat them as NVARCHAR.

What am I missing?  I can certainly rewrite the stored procedure to take strings instead of dates and let SQL do the conversion, but it really seems I should be able to pass dates from Powershell to SQL.

There must be a solution to this. What is causing the $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() to change the datatype of my inputs?  Or, am I setting up the $cmd.Parameters incorrectly?

Kind thanks for any help.

Comment: Don’t use `AddWithValue`. https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Very kind thanks. This resolved the problem.  For anyone else using SQLPS, I needed to type my variables in this manner:     $cmd.Parameters.Add("@SourceDate", [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlDataType]::dateTime).Value = $startDate;  But it worked!!! THANK YOU!